# Prestashop 1.6 CustomerAccountForm

Tags: module, hook, registration, prestashop-1.6

I created my payment module. During module's instalation i'm creating new table **ps_mymodule_card** with **id**, **customer_id** and **card_number** fields.

In register page I added new text input (**card_nubmer**) in account register page using **hookCreateAccountForm()** in module. It displays proper but how to get **customer id** in function **hookCreateAccount($params)** inside my payment module? I want to add own post data to database during (or just after) user register .

Answer (score 0):

***modules/mypaymentmodule/mypaymentmodule.php***

```
public function hookCreateAccountForm()
    {
        return '<!--new field in form-->'
        . '<div class="form-group">'
            . '<label for="card_number">'
                . 'Card number:'
            . '</label>'
            . '<input class="form-control" id="card_number" type="text" name="card_number">'
            . '</div>'
            . '<!--new field in form-->';
    }

    public function hookCreateAccount($params)
    {
            [here put some validation of data]

            $cadrNumber = $params['_POST']['card_number'];
            $customer = $params['newCustomer'];

            $db = Db::getInstance();
            $query = 'INSERT INTO `'._DB_PREFIX_.'mymodule_card`
                    (`customer_id`, `card_number`)
                    VALUES
                    ("'.intval($customer->id).'", "'.  intval($cadrNumber).'")';
            $db->Execute($query);
    }
```

function below is calling of course during module instalation!

```
private function _createMymoduleCardTbl()
    {
        $db = Db::getInstance();
        $query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `"._DB_PREFIX_."mymodule_card` (
                                `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
                                `customer_id` INT NOT NULL ,
                                `card_number` TEXT NOT NULL
                                ) ENGINE = MYISAM ";

        $db->Execute($query);

        return TRUE;
    }
```

do not forget about hooks registering in install method!!

```
$this->registerHook('createAccountForm')
$this->registerHook('createAccount')
```